# How to update TabSpec content (ex. add textView)

Tags: android

I am very new to Android so go easy on me. I have implemented an activity that makes use of the TabSpec to make 2 tabs. I can get them running with content loading from the xml layouts.

My question is how can I add/change content of one of the tabs? Lets use adding a textview as an example. How would I do this?

```
    //set up tabs
    TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

    tabs.setup();

    //indicate setting for first tab
    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Templates");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    //indicate setting second tab
    spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Stat Sheets");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
```

Here is my XML

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/tabhost"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/tab1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
/*I want to add content here at runtime*/
  </LinearLayout>

  <Button android:id="@+id/tab2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="A semi-random button"
  />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: just add a textview in the xml..hide it be default and make it visible whenever you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out TabSpec approach is a little dated. I turned to properly implementing fragments which turned out to be much more concise and straightforward. I followed this tutorial specifically which really helped.
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/